# Are there any equivalent of C/C++ __FILE__ and __LINE__ macros in R?

Tags: r, s-plus

I'm trying to get the equivalent of **FILE** or **LINE** macros in C or C++ in R (or S+). Any ideas?

**FILE** The presumed name of the current source ﬁle (a character string literal).

**LINE** The presumed line number (within the current source ﬁle) of the current source line (an integer constant).

As for context - I have log messages being flushed to console from different sections of the code, and given that the messages themselves are built at run-time, it is often very difficult to find out where this log message is coming from (with the size of the R code growing to many thousand lines and running on a distributed grid). However if I could dump the FILE and LINE number along with the log messages, it would be much easier to trace the logs...

Comment: When asking about the equivalent of X in language Y, it's often best to provide some context on why you need such a tool and what you're using it for. That helps people who know R but not C/C++ brainstorm possible solutions.

Comment: I edited your question to add FILE and LINE description. But as said in comment, we need context of the question, even for people that know the 2 languages..the context here is not obvious.

Comment: This might be interesting https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-June/314916.html

Comment: If you can log the name of the function , maybe you can use `getAnywhere` to find it..

Comment: If you're at all familiar with `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in C/C++, then it hardly matters exactly what the OP needs them for in R... it's implicitly because they need to access the file and/or line number of their code... How is that not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `#line` directive.  The structure is `#line nn "filename"`.  See Duncan's Murdoch's [article on source references](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Murdoch.pdf) for more.

Comment: #line nn "filename"
where nn is an integer. As with the same-named
directive in the C language, this tells the parser to
assume that the next line of source is line nn from
the given filename for the purpose of constructing
source references.

Comment: This is note exactly what I want though! It requires to put the directive here and there with line numbers which will soon get lost with code/files being moved around... I wonder if there may not be a solution here... :-/